# Prototype keep checkbox selected after page reload

Tags: custom, prototype-js

I am using `prototype` in Magento custom module and have a requirement to keep the checkbox selected after page reload if its clicked. The scenarios are as under:

1. Keep checkbox unchecked when the page loads first time.
2. If user clicks on checkbox and reload the page, keep the checkbox
   selected.
3. If user unchecks and reload the page, keep the checkbox unchecked.

How could I achieve this using prototype ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without any code samples to start from I'm just guessing at what you mean.  Did you try anything yet?

```
if (window.sessionStorage) document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var checkbox = $('id-of-checkbox');
    checkbox.setValue(sessionStorage.getItem('key-of-checkbox'));
    checkbox.observe('change', function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('key-of-checkbox', $F(checkbox));
    });
});
```